# generating a bar graph with php html making percentages display correctly?

Tags: php, html, graph

Can anyone help me out im trying to do a simple code with php and html, my goal is to get my variable via database and post the number and add a % at the end but with my code it's confusing to me.

The very last one works but its hardcoded.

Click here for image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Apoh.png
The yellow graph i wat to dispay at 55% and the rest wont be filled in such as the bottom graph.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .red {background-color: red;}
    .green {background-color: green;}
    .yellow{background-color: yellow;}
    .bar { width: 15%; border: 1px solid #000; background: grey; }
    </style>


    <?php   
    if ($percentage >= 51 && $percentage <= 74) {
    echo "<div class=\"bar\" align=\"left\"><div class=\"yellow\" style=\"width: $percentage %\">$percentage test</div></div>";
    } else if ($percentage >= 75){
    echo "<div class=\"bar\" align=\"left\"><div class=\"green\" style=\"width: $percentage \"%\">$percentage test</div></div>";
    } else if ($percentage >= 0 && $percentage <= 50) {
    echo "<div class=\"bar\" align=\"left\"><div class=\"red\" style=\"width:46%\">$percentage test</div></div>";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see how you get percentage value but I can see that you define your style in 3 different ways:
The first would produce : width: 33 px; which is somehow correct but the 2nd is wrong the right is :

```
echo "<div class=\"bar\" align=\"left\"><div class=\"red\" style=\"width:$percenage%\">$percentage test</div></div>";
```

or

```
echo "<div class=\"bar\" align=\"left\"><div class=\"red\" style=\"width:".$percentage."%\">$percentage test</div></div>";
```

This is to complete the above answer.
I forgot you can use the !important argument also.
... width:$percantage% !important;

Comment: yep i sure did sorry new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

You can not put variable inside string like that. So you should do this:

```
if ($percentage >= 51 && $percentage <= 74)
    echo "<div class=\"bar\" align=\"left\"><div class=\"yellow\" style=\"width:". $percentage." %\">".$percentage." test</div></div>";
```

Comment: Still nothing i think this would work if it were in a table maybe?